# http://127.0.0.1:5000/post/0 isnt working

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask   

app = Flask(__name__)
posts = {0: dict(title='Hello World', content='This is my first ever post !'}

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/post/(int:post_id)') 
def post(post_id):
    post = posts.get(post_id)
    return f"Post {post['title']} , content:\n\n{post['content']}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: For dynamic routes inside flask you have to use `<>` instead of `()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')`. Note the `<>`.